# Is there a possible way to delete an item using position in the dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

so I ran into this problem. Let's say I have a dictionary, and I want to delete the last item without knowing the item's key name. How would I do so?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: dictionaries don't have a position in the sense that lists do, while dictionaries are ordered by insertion order in Python as of 3.7, you should explicitly be removing entries by using keys, not assuming a certain order

Comment: What does `list(my_dict.keys())` give you? Can you get the last element from that list? If you can, can you use it with `del`?  Give it a try :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use `popitem()`

*(from Python 3.5+ for OrderedDict, 3.7+ for all dictionaries)*:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3}

d.popitem() # ('c',3)

print(d)

{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

popitem() works like a LIFO queue (stack) so it removes the last added key.  To delete the first item, you can use popitem(False) which works like a FIFO queue.

To delete some other arbitrary position, you can use `itertools.islice` to help:

```
from itertools import islice

d = {'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5}

del d[next(islice(d,2,None))]  # delete at index 2

print(d)

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

*This still needs to run through keys sequentially but at least it doesn't create an intermediate data structure (list) to do so.*

Answer (score 2):

You pop the last item like this:

```
dictionary = {'a': 2, 'd': 3}
last_key = list(dictionary)[-1]
dictionary.pop(last_key)
print(dictionary)
```

Output

```
{'a': 2}
```

From Python3.7 dicts [keep](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) the order of keys. So, `list(dictionary)` represents keys in their insertion order

Comment: Use `last_key = next(reversed(dictionary))` for better efficiency

Comment: Dictionaries are only reversible from Python version 3.8 onward though.